# how to build correctly wxWidgets 3.0.2 on visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wxwidgets

I downloaded and extracted wxWidgets3.0.2 and then opened the folder `wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw` I found `wx_vc12.sln` so I run it from MSVC IDE then a message asked me to upgrade compiler and libraries, I accepted.

I opened from msvc: `build->batch build`. I selected all (checked all) then pressed build...

build began; it took some minutes. when it finishes it said to me that 35 errors and 35 warnings were found eg:

`Error C1189    #error: Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration (compiling source file ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_aux.c)  wxtiff  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\stdio.h    1927`

and one of the warnings:

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning C4005   'snprintf': macro redefinition (compiling source file ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_write.c)   wxtiff  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\stdio.h    1925`

I um using windows 7 professional x64 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

now when I try to build some sample ignoring the errors and warnings it said: link1104: cannot open file 'wxtiffd.lib'.

if I open the lib directory searching for the named above file I find it only under extension 'pdb': 'wxtiffd.pdb'.

Comment: could you please post the error you received when building the library itself? Also, how did you build the library - from Terminal or IDE? And what steps did you perform to do it?

Comment: @Igor: I edited the topic adding much details, would pay it a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wxWidgets 3.0.2 will not compile with VS 2015 without some patching. The best alternative could be to use the [WX_3_0_BRANCH](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/WX_3_0_BRANCH) from Git, which is basically wxWidgets 3.0.2 + some fixes.

Comment: yes I downloaded 3.0.1 and it worked fine. the only matter is that the folder is about 11 gb can I delete files I don't need? which ones I don't need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest git sources from 3.0 branch or apply [this fix](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/c06c8edb5a275682f16a44a048b9de79332e2b5f) manually, 3.0.2 had been done before MSVS 2015 release and so, unfortunately, doesn't compile with it out of the box.

Comment: I got it to work fine. the only matter is that the folder is about 11 gb can I delete files I don't need? which ones I don't need?